# Can i change UIPickerView separator height?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uipickerview, picker

I have implemented a picker view but now I want to change the picker view separator line height. I want more thicker separator liner rather than this default line. So is this possible to change height of separator???

[image]

I want line as below image.

[image]

Comment: You want to change row height?

Comment: @tdakus I want to change separator height as i mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change the line view's height in the pickerView's delegate method:

```
public func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
    for view in pickerView.subviews {
        if view.frame.size.height < 1 {
            var frame = view.frame
            frame.size.height = 2
            view.frame = frame
            view.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
        }
    }

    let label = UILabel()
    label.text = "Test Text" //remember to change it to the real data
    label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.center
    return label
}
```

Remember to set PickerView's delegate:

```
self.pickerView.delegate = self //or do this in XIB or Storyboard.
```

The effects:
[image]

Comment: Instead of doing all this, you can simple use this [delegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerviewdelegate/1614386-pickerview) and return your required height. Thats it.

Comment: @dahiya_boy, no, you are wrong. The `rowHeightForComponent` method gives the whole row area height. What AdmV needs is just to change the line's height.